# android - URL encode from user input

Tags: android, string, parsing, android-volley, urlencode

I will encode user input into a single URL, I use Uri.encode but error response remains 400. how to make the encode work?

the result is that "space" is replaced with "%20" but the response still fails

And this is my code.,

```
public void OnQuerySubmit() {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            String UrlEncode = AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS + Uri.encode(query);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Mencari...");
            showDialog();
            jobList.clear();
            getJobs(UrlEncode);
            homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            hideDialog();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public List<Job> getJobs(String urlGetjobs) {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlGetjobs, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
            try {

                boolean error = response.getBoolean("error");

                if(!error) {
                    JSONArray  transaksiArray = response.getJSONArray("transaksi");
                    for(int i = 0; i < transaksiArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject seluruhTrans = transaksiArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Job job = new Job();
                job.setTitle(seluruhTrans.getString("title"));
                job.setNamaPerusahaan(seluruhTrans.getString("nama_perusahaan"));
                job.setLokasi(seluruhTrans.getString("lokasi"));
                job.setKriteria_1(seluruhTrans.getString("kriteria_1"));
                job.setKriteria_2(seluruhTrans.getString("kriteria_2"));
                job.setKriteria_3(seluruhTrans.getString("kriteria_3"));
                job.setGaji(seluruhTrans.getString("gaji"));
                job.setImg_logo(seluruhTrans.getString("img_logo"));
                job.setTanggal(seluruhTrans.getString("tanggal"));
                job.setId_post(seluruhTrans.getString("id_post"));

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("title", job.getTitle());
                editor.putString("nama_perusahaan", job.getNamaPerusahaan());
                editor.putString("lokasi", job.getLokasi());
                editor.putString("kriteria_1", job.getKriteria_1());
                editor.putString("kriteria_2", job.getKriteria_2());
                editor.putString("kriteria_3", job.getKriteria_3());
                editor.putString("gaji", job.getGaji());
                editor.putString("img_logo", job.getImg_logo());
                editor.putString("tanggal", job.getTanggal());
                editor.putString("id_post", job.getId_post());
                editor.commit();

                jobList.add(job);
                        }
                }
                homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError || error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Check your Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    return jobList;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code? You need to check your encoded url is valid or not, better use retrofit or volley. you don't need to encode you url.

Comment: public void OnQuerySubmit(){
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
  String UrlEncode = AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS + Uri.encode(query);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Mencari...");
                showDialog();

                jobList.clear();
                getJobs(UrlEncode);
                homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideDialog();
                return false;
            }

Comment: add this code in your question also `getJobs()` method code.

Comment: I use volley, I have made its API based on input from a user. like this: http: //xxxx.xxx.xx/search/: title
": title" is a single unified url for the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    jobList = new ArrayList<>();

    homeRecyclerViewAdapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), jobList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeRecyclerViewAdapter);
    getJobs(""); //get your data as it is

    OnQuerySubmit();

    return view;

}

public void OnQuerySubmit() {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            getJobs(query);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void getJobs(final String query) {
    StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    jobList.clear();
                    JSONArray transaksiArray = jsonObject.JSONArray("transaksi");
                        ....
                        ....
                        ....
                    jobList.add(job);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(Tag, error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(query){
                map.put("title", query);
            }else{}
            return map;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: This works, but I have an array of data for recyclerview. Sorry I forgot the name of the url / searchAll / (to get everything) and / searchAll /: title (to get by input) So I want beside the recyclerview with public List <Job> it works, I also want to use getJobs method to get all recyclerview by title

Comment: @MuhammadImanudin sorry bro but i'm not understanding what are you trying to say?

Comment: I have recyclerview data on arraylist. API I have designed first to get all listdata from server URL: (/ searchAll), secondly I want to get list of data based on title of user input with API URL: (/ searchAll /: title). So I want to use the getJobs (query) method, then the recyclerview will get what the user wants. If so, should I create the getJobs () method again?

Sorry, if very convoluted,

Comment: just pass `getJobs("");` and in map check `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(query){             map.put("title", query);}else{} return map;` if there is query it will add into map otherwise blankmap will send

Comment: getJobs() method before using public List<Job>getJobs(String urlgetjobs) ... if I do not use List <Job> and replaced with public void getJobs () .. will it later display the entire data arraylist?

Comment: `public List<Job>getJobs` is redundant. because volley is asynchronous. you list never returns. notify adapter in onResponse method is enough

Comment: Not successful bro :( I tried, but the data does not load full.
At the time of oncreate I create new Arraylist (), then jobList = getJobs (urlconfig); but when I enter the query in getJobs () it is not fulfilled.
@AbhishekSingh

Comment: please check my update code. sorry i updated it in comment field

@AbhishekSingh

Comment: Ohh thank you friend, I just got it. It turns out I just need to send params only, my mistake while designing the API. thank you

Comment: Hello @Abhishek Singh :)
Can you help me? I want to try using tablayout with recyclerview inside fragment, but the recyclerview is blank..

Link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019482/android-implement-recyclerview-with-tablayout-inside-fragment

before, the most recent problem is over..

Answer (score 0):

```
 package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Adapter.HomeRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Helper.AppController;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Model.Job;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.R;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Util.AppConfig;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private HomeRecyclerViewAdapter homeRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private List<Job> jobList;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    private MaterialSearchView searchView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        return homeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        jobList = new ArrayList<>();
        jobList = getJobs(AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS);

        homeRecyclerViewAdapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), jobList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(homeRecyclerViewAdapter);
        homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        OnQuerySubmit();

        return view;

    }


    public void OnQuerySubmit(){
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String UrlEncode = AppConfig.URL_GETJOBS + Uri.encode(query);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Mencari...");
                showDialog();

                jobList.clear();
                getJobs(UrlEncode);
                homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideDialog();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public List<Job> getJobs(String urlGetjobs) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlGetjobs, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                try {

                    boolean error = response.getBoolean("error");

                    if(!error) {
                      JSONArray  transaksiArray = response.getJSONArray("transaksi");
                    for(int i = 0; i < transaksiArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject seluruhTrans = transaksiArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Job job = new Job();
                        job.setTitle(seluruhTrans.getString("title"));
                        job.setNamaPerusahaan(seluruhTrans.getString("nama_perusahaan"));
                        job.setLokasi(seluruhTrans.getString("lokasi"));
                        job.setKriteria_1(seluruhTrans.getString("kriteria_1"));
                        job.setKriteria_2(seluruhTrans.getString("kriteria_2"));
                        job.setKriteria_3(seluruhTrans.getString("kriteria_3"));
                        job.setGaji(seluruhTrans.getString("gaji"));
                        job.setImg_logo(seluruhTrans.getString("img_logo"));
                        job.setTanggal(seluruhTrans.getString("tanggal"));
                        job.setId_post(seluruhTrans.getString("id_post"));

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("title", job.getTitle());
                        editor.putString("nama_perusahaan", job.getNamaPerusahaan());
                        editor.putString("lokasi", job.getLokasi());
                        editor.putString("kriteria_1", job.getKriteria_1());
                        editor.putString("kriteria_2", job.getKriteria_2());
                        editor.putString("kriteria_3", job.getKriteria_3());
                        editor.putString("gaji", job.getGaji());
                        editor.putString("img_logo", job.getImg_logo());
                        editor.putString("tanggal", job.getTanggal());
                        editor.putString("id_post", job.getId_post());
                        editor.commit();

                        jobList.add(job);
                        }
                    }
                    homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof NoConnectionError || error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Check your Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        return jobList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }



    public void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
    public void hideDialog(){
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
  }






HomeRecyclerviewAdapter.java

package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Adapter;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities.HomeFragment;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities.HomeFragmentDetail;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Model.Job;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by master on 12/12/17.
 */

public class HomeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Job> jobList;

    public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Job> jobs){
        this.context = context;
        jobList = jobs;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.home_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Job job = jobList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(job.getTitle());
    holder.namaPerusahaan.setText(job.getNamaPerusahaan());
    holder.kriteria_1.setText(job.getKriteria_1());
    holder.kriteria_2.setText(job.getKriteria_2());
    holder.kriteria_3.setText(job.getKriteria_3());
    holder.gaji.setText(job.getGaji());
    holder.lokasi.setText(job.getLokasi());
    holder.tanggal.setText(job.getTanggal());

    String img_logoLink = job.getImg_logo();
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(img_logoLink) // URL
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).centerCrop().dontAnimate()
//                         .centerCrop(), .crossFade(), .thumbnail(), .dontAnimate(), .dontTransform() BitmapTransformation(.circleCrop())
                )
                .into(holder.img_logo); //TARGET GAMBAR YANG NAK DIUBAH

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

         TextView title;
         TextView namaPerusahaan;
         TextView lokasi;
         TextView kriteria_1;
         TextView kriteria_2;
         TextView kriteria_3;
         TextView gaji;
         ImageView img_logo;
         TextView tanggal;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView, final Context ctx) {
            super(itemView);
            context = ctx;
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
            namaPerusahaan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.namaPerusahaanID);
            kriteria_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.satuTv);
            kriteria_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duaTv);
            kriteria_3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tigaTv);
            gaji = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gajiID);
            lokasi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lokasiID);
            img_logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_logoID);
            tanggal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tanggalID);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    HomeFragmentDetail fragmentDetail = new HomeFragmentDetail();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Job job = jobList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    bundle.putSerializable("job", job);
                    fragmentDetail.setArguments(bundle);

                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) itemView.getContext();

                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragmenthome, fragmentDetail);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

////                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeDetailActivity.class);
////                    intent.putExtra("job", job);
////                    ctx.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}

HomeFragmentDetail.java
package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Model.Job;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * to handle interaction events.
 */
public class HomeFragmentDetail extends Fragment {

    private TextView tvDeskripsi;
    private TextView tvIndustri;

    public HomeFragmentDetail() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeFragmentDetail newInstance(){
        HomeFragmentDetail homeFragmentDetail = new HomeFragmentDetail();
        return homeFragmentDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragment_detail, container, false);
        tvDeskripsi = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDeskripsi);
        tvIndustri = view.findViewById(R.id.tvIndustri);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        Job job = (Job) bundle.getSerializable("job");

        String PostID = job.getId_post();
        String titleID = job.getTitle();

        tvDeskripsi.setText(PostID);
        tvIndustri.setText(titleID);

        return view;


//    DataHolder dataholder=new DataHolder("1","TestName");
//    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
//    bundle.putSerializable("obj",dataholder);

//    Fragment fragment=new FragmentB();
//    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
//    fragmentManager = getActivity(). getSupportFragmentManager();
//    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager .beginTransaction();
//    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
//    fragmentTransaction.commit();

        //Job job = (Job) getIntent.getSerializableExtra("job");

//        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
//        Job job = (Job) bundle.getSerializable("job");
//        String jobID = job.getId_post();
//        String titleID = job.getTitle();



    }

}

AppConfig.java

package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Util;

/**
 * Created by master on 10/12/17.
 */

public class AppConfig {

    public static final String URL = "http://192.168.43.142/Carekkerje/v1";
    public static final String URL_REGISTER = URL + "/daftarUser";
    public static final String URL_LOGIN = URL + "/loginUser";
    public static final String URL_GETJOBS = URL + "/seluruhLowongan/";
    public static final String URL_GETJOBSS = URL + "/seluruhLowongan/:title";

}
```